# Selecting nodes in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to select nodes using xpath in c#

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Some other title</title>
        <item>
            <description><![CDATA[<img src="http://www.site.com/image.jps"/><br />]]></description>

        </item>
        <item>
            <title>This title</title>
            <subtitle><subtitle>
            <Date>Fri, 21 Mar 2014 08:30:44 GMT</Date>
            <description>Some description</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>The other title</title>
            <subtitle><subtitle>
            <Date>Fri, 21 Mar 2014 08:30:44 GMT</Date>
            <description>The other description</description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

This is my incorrect code so far:

```
            // Load the document and set the root element.
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("file.xml");

            // Select nodes
            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/channel/item/");

            foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeList)
            {
                string fieldLine = xn["Title"].InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Title: ", fieldLine);
            }
```

What I want to output the "title" from "item" like this:

```
This title
The other title
```

Please let me know if you know how to do this

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: `subtitle` elements are not closed in your xml. I believe its just a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var titles = from i in xdoc.Root.Element("channel").Elements("item")
             select (string)i.Element("title");
```

Or with XPath:

```
var titles = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("rss/channel/item/title")
                 .Select(t => (string)t);
```

That returns `IEnumerable<string>` with titles.

```
foreach (string title in titles)
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", title); // note item placeholder in format
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the full path from the `rss` root:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item[title]/");
foreach(...)
```

(Since not all `<item>`s have titles, exclude ones which do not).
Also, note that `xml` is case sensitive:

```
string fieldLine = xn["title"].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the below points, and you will get the required output..

1)Subtitle in your posted question is missing end tags, Please put'/' in End tag

2) You were very close to the right code, please replace it with:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("file.xml");

        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item/title");

        foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", xn.InnerText);
        }
```